# sink() within source() in R not working properly

Tags: r, output, text-files, sink

I have the following code:

```
source("file.R")
```

and file.R includes:

```
tab<-table(variable)
sink("variable.txt")
tab
sink()
```

However, the variable.txt file is empty.
Any idea why ? I am using RStudio Version 0.99.902 and R version 3.3.1, on a Mac OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6).

A colleague of mine told me, this code works well for him under Windows.

Any help appreciated.
Best regards !

Comment: Try `print(tab)`, or `source('file.R', print.eval = T)`